# Passing State value, or State, as Composable function parameter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In a Composable function, I can pass as parameter the State, or the value of the State. Any reason for preferring to pass the value of the State, instead of the State?

In both cases, the composable is stateless, so why should I distinguish both cases?

Comment: Please let me know if you got the answer, thanks

Comment: @MadhuKumarDadi No I didn`t get any answer to my question. Thanks

Comment: Is there any clue regarding this? I need to know the answer too?

Comment: @JayCraig I provided an answer below. Could you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 11):

There is a slight difference between passing `State` or just the value of a `State` regarding recomposition.

Let's start with passing `State`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example1(text: State<String>) {
  SideEffect { Log.d("Example", "Example1 recomposition") }
  Example2(text)
}

@Composable
fun Example2(text: State<String>) {
  SideEffect { Log.d("Example", "Example2 recomposition") }
  Text(text.value)
}

@Composable
fun Screen() {
  val text = remember { mutableStateOf("hello") } }

  Example1(text)

  Button(
    onClick = { text.value = "world" }
  ) {
    Text("Click me")
  }
}
```

On first start you will see the log output

```
Example1 recomposition
Example2 recomposition
```

However when you click the button, you will only see an additional

```
Example2 recomposition
```

Because you're passing down `State` and only `Example2` is reading the state, `Example1` does not need to be recomposed.

Let's change the parameters to a plain type:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example1(text: String) {
  SideEffect { Log.d("Example", "Example1 recomposition") }
  Example2(text)
}

@Composable
fun Example2(text: String) {
  SideEffect { Log.d("Example", "Example2 recomposition") }
  Text(text)
}

@Composable
fun Screen() {
  val text = remember { mutableStateOf("hello") } }

  Example1(text.value)

  Button(
    onClick = { text.value = "world" }
  ) {
    Text("Click me")
  }
}
```

When you click the button now, you will see two additional lines in the log output

```
Example1 recomposition
Example2 recomposition
```

Since `text` is now a plain type of the function signatures of both composables, both need to be recomposed when the value changes.

**However** always passing down `State` can become quite cumbersome. Compose is quite good at detecting what needs to be recomposed so this should be considered a micro optimization. I just wanted to point out that there is a slight difference which every developer using Compose should know about.

Answer (score 4):

Short: **Pass the State object**

Although sven Jacobs answer is totally correct, I just want to add more explanation.
Here's a summary of the difference:

- **Passing a State object:** Only the composable functions that read the state value will be recomposed when the state changes. Composable functions that don't read the state value won't be recomposed.
- **Passing the value of a State:** Any change to the value will trigger recomposition of the composable function, regardless of whether it directly reads the value or not.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to pass state's value. For example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)
        val onClickAtButton = {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                isLoading.value = true
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    //Do some heavy operation live REST call
                }
                isLoading.value = false
            }
        }

        setContent {
            MyComposable(isLoading.value, onClickAtButton)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    isLoading: Boolean = false,
    onClickAtButton: () -> Unit = {}
){

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(){
    
        Button(onClick = onClickAtButton)

        if(isLoading){
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.